# C# I²C sender Thread via wiringPi

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

Im trying to do a I²C Sending Worker with a working list.

Im saveing the I²C Commands in a ConCurrentQueue and try to send it via the wiringPi Libary

Im new to Threading and Queues, thats why i cant figure out how to do it the right way.

I tried this, but it wont work at all :D

Would be nice if someone could have a look at this an tell me what im doing wrong.

```
class worker
{
    public bool enabled = false;
    public struct i2c_command
    {
        public int chip_number;
        public byte subadress;
        public byte data;
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<i2c_command> i2c_commandsList = new ConcurrentQueue<i2c_command>();

    public void write_i2c(int cn, byte sa, byte data)
    {
        i2c_command i2c_c = new i2c_command();
        i2c_c.chip_number = cn;
        i2c_c.subadress = sa;
        i2c_c.data = data;
        i2c_commandsList.Enqueue(i2c_c);
    }

    public void i2c_worker()
    {
        enabled = true;
        while (enabled = true)
        {
            i2c_command i2c_send = new i2c_command();
            i2c_commandsList.TryDequeue(out i2c_send);

            WiringPi.I2C.wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(i2c_send.chip_number, i2c_send.subadress, i2c_send.data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is starting the Thread:

```
worker worker = new worker();
ThreadStart i2c_sender_ref = new ThreadStart(worker.i2c_worker);
Thread i2c_sender = new Thread(i2c_sender_ref);
i2c_sender.Start();
```

Comment: You should consider posting this in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you show the code where you create & start the thread to do the I2C write.

Comment: The main function i look for has nothing to do with Raspberry... Im just looking for the ConcurrentQueue and how i can use it in my example

Comment: @PaulF I am initializing the "worker" class in the "main" function and starting a thread with the "i2c_worker" fuction, so I can add commands to the Thread via the "write_i2c fuction"

Comment: Seeing your code would help more than you trying to explain what you are trying to do - what is your "worker" class? the "i2c_worker" does not start a thread, it consists of a while loop (which has an error in it, btw).

Comment: @PaulF added and corrected the i2c_worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you do not check if you get a command from the queue - your code needs to be more like this :

```
public void i2c_worker()
{
    enabled = true;
    while (enabled)
    {
        i2c_command i2c_send;
        if (i2c_commandsList.TryDequeue(out i2c_send))
            WiringPi.I2C.wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(i2c_send.chip_number, i2c_send.subadress, i2c_send.data);
    }
}
```